# How in one controller get value from another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have an angular application. Using ui-select.

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="FlatController as flat">
   <form ng-submit="flat.createFlat()">
      <ui-select ng-model="flat.flatData.typelocal" theme="bootstrap">
          <ui-select-match placeholder="Type" id="localtype">
              {{ $select.selected.type }}
          </ui-select-match>
          <ui-select-choices repeat="uitypelocal.type as uitypelocal in flat.typelocal1 track by $index | filter: $select.search">
             <div ng-bind-html="uitypelocal.type | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
       <button class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

In form i have some inputs and selects. Now, i want to have in the select data from another controller. How can i do it?

I have a service:

```
angular.module('flatService', [])
    .factory('Flat', function($http){
        var flatFactory = {};

        flatFactory.allFlats = function(){
            return $http.get('/api/flats');
        };

        flatFactory.create = function(flatData){
            return $http.post('/api/addflat', flatData);
        };

        return flatFactory;

    })
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to call one controller into another there are five methods available

1. $rootScope.$emit() and $rootScope.$broadcast()
2. If Second controller is child ,you can use Parent child communication .
3. Use Services
4. Kind of hack - with the help of angular.element()
5. inject '$controller'

> **1. $rootScope.$emit() and $rootScope.$broadcast()**

Controller and its scope can get destroyed,
but the $rootScope remains across the application, that's why we are taking $rootScope because $rootScope is parent of all scopes .

If you are performing communication from parent to child and even child wants to communicate with its siblings, you can use $broadcast

If you are performing communication from child to parent ,no siblings invovled then you can use $rootScope.$emit

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl" class="ng-scope">
      // ParentCtrl
      <div ng-controller="Sibling1" class="ng-scope">
        // Sibling first controller
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="Sibling2" class="ng-scope">
        // Sibling Second controller
        <div ng-controller="Child" class="ng-scope">
          // Child controller
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Angularjs Code

```
 var app =  angular.module('myApp',[]);//We will use it throughout the example 
    app.controller('Child', function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.$emit('childEmit', 'Child calling parent');
      $rootScope.$broadcast('siblingAndParent');
    });

app.controller('Sibling1', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('childEmit', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data + ' Inside Sibling one');
  });
  $rootScope.$on('siblingAndParent', function(event, data) {
    console.log('broadcast from child in parent');
  });
});

app.controller('Sibling2', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('childEmit', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data + ' Inside Sibling two');
  });
  $rootScope.$on('siblingAndParent', function(event, data) {
    console.log('broadcast from child in parent');
  });
});

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('childEmit', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data + ' Inside parent controller');
  });
  $rootScope.$on('siblingAndParent', function(event, data) {
    console.log('broadcast from child in parent');
  });
});
```

In above code console of $emit 'childEmit' will not call inside child siblings  and It will call inside only parent, where $broadcast get called inside siblings and parent as well.This is the place where performance come into a action.$emit is preferrable, if you are using child to parent communication because it skips some dirty checks.

> **2. If Second controller is child, you can use Child Parent communication**

Its one of the best method, If you want to do **child parent communication** where child wants to communicate with **immediate parent** then it would not need any kind $broadcast or $emit but if you want to do communication from parent to child then you have to use either service or $broadcast

For example HTML:-

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
 <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
 </div>
</div>
```

Angularjs

```
 app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.value='Its parent';
      });
  app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log($scope.value);
  });
```

Whenever you are using child to parent communication, Angularjs will search for a variable inside child, If it is not present inside then it will choose to see the values inside parent controller.

> **3.Use Services**

AngularJS supports the concepts of *"Seperation of Concerns"* using services architecture. Services are javascript functions and are responsible to do a specific tasks only.This makes them an **individual entity** which is **maintainable and testable**.Services used to inject using Dependency Injection mecahnism of Angularjs.

Angularjs code:

```
app.service('communicate',function(){
  this.communicateValue='Hello';
});

app.controller('ParentCtrl',function(communicate){//Dependency Injection
  console.log(communicate.communicateValue+" Parent World");
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl',function(communicate){//Dependency Injection
  console.log(communicate.communicateValue+" Child World");
});
```

It will give output Hello Child World and Hello Parent World . According to Angular docs of services *Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory*.

> **4.Kind of hack - with the help of angular.element()**

This method gets scope() from the element by its Id / unique class.angular.element() method returns element and scope() gives $scope variable of another variable using $scope variable of one controller inside another is not a good practice.

HTML:-

```
<div id='parent' ng-controller='ParentCtrl'>{{varParent}}
 <span ng-click='getValueFromChild()'>Click to get ValueFormChild</span>
 <div id='child' ng-controller='childCtrl'>{{varChild}}
   <span ng-click='getValueFromParent()'>Click to get ValueFormParent </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Angularjs:-

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.varParent="Hello Parent";
  $scope.getValueFromChild=function(){
  var childScope=angular.element('#child').scope();
  console.log(childScope.varChild);
  }
});

app.controller('CarentCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.varChild="Hello Child";
  $scope.getValueFromParent=function(){
  var parentScope=angular.element('#parent').scope();
  console.log(parentScope.varParent);
  }
});
```

In above code controllers are showing their own value on Html and when you will click on text you will get values in console accordingly.If you click on parent controllers span, browser will console value of child and viceversa.

> **5.inject '$controller'**

You can inject '$controller' service in your parent controller(MessageCtrl) and then instantiate/inject the child controller(DateCtrl) using:
`$scope.childController = $controller('childController', { $scope: $scope.$new() });`

Now you can access data from your child controller by calling its methods as it is a service.
Let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 2):

The view's scope is determine by it's controller. However, angular allows nested view scope inheritance, meaning that a view nested inside another view has access to the parent view's scope.. for example:

```
<div ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
   <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
      ...
   </div>
<div>
```

the inner div would have access to the InnerCtrl's scope as well as the OuterCtrl's scope, but the outer div would only have access to the OuterCtrl's scope.

If you need data shared between non-related controllers (those that are not related by nested views), then the data should be provided by a service that can be injected into the controllers like:

```
app.factory('service', function() {
   ...
   return {
     data: someData
   };
});

app.controller('ctrl1', [... function(..., service) {
    $scope.data = service.data;
}]);

app.controller('ctrl2', [... function(..., service) {
    $scope.data = service.data;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to have in the ui-select data from second controller, and want to save in model of first controller (using mondodb)

Comment: @EugeniuszZuev - Ok, so when you make a selection in one controller, you want the data to update in another? Sounds like you want to use service combined with eventing to push the changes from the service to the second controller... check my answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565430/angularjs-how-to-get-actual-factorys-data-in-controller/31565601#31565601

Comment: No, in second controller i have some data(for example, type: String, name: Sting, street: String). Now, in first controller i want to have in the select all streets from the second controller. The chosen one i save to the schema of the first controller.

Answer (score 0):

use $broadcase or $emit event like:

```
app.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("CustomEvent", function($event, data){
      alert(data);
    })
}]);

app.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.$emit("CustomEvent", "SecondControllerValue");
}]);
```